# I can not move the text

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Text is not moving, I tried to use `justifyContent`, `alignItems` and `textAlign` but not working. Working on `visual studio` and `react-native`, using my phone to emulator. 
you can see the code ^^ 
I hope that u can help me

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  Picker,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./resim.jpg')}
        style={styles.container}>
        <View styles={styles.overlayContainer}>
          <View styles={styles.top}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>FIRST</Text>
          </View>         
        </View>         
      </ImageBackground>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },

  overlayContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(47,163,218, .4)',

  },
  top: {
    height: '50%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  header: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 28
  }

});
```

Please help me guys please.

Comment: What do you mean by `Text is not moving`? Please be more specific

Comment: There is a text in code "FIRST" it stuck on the left corner, but i want to locate it in the center

Answer (score 0):

overlayContainer: { flex: 1,backgroundColor:'rgba(47,163,218, .4)' },

top: { height: '50%', alignItems: 'center',justifyContent:    'center',backgroundColor: 'white' },

header: { color: '#fff', fontSize: 28 }

Try:

Add width size for top style and overlayContainer style